# Data Update on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and tried to check snowflake on AWS. I understood that AWS is using S3 as storage layer. But if S3 is used to store the data, how come snowflake is allowing updates on the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way Snowflake stores and manages data is very specific to Snowflake and is key to a lot of its unique functionality. While it supports the standard SQL commands, what it is actually doing in the background is not what you might think: it does not update data - instead it will insert new data and mark the existing data as "old". In the same way, it does not delete data when a user issues a "delete" command; instead it will flag the data as deleted and at some point in the future (depending on the type of account you have with Snowflake and how you've configured the account) it will physically delete your "deleted" and "old" data.

It is this way of working that enables you to undrop tables and do "time travel" on your data e.g. query as it was in a specific point in the past